# On selecting the text in message and scrolling up or down the blue highlight comes over the textbox and navbar

Tags: html, ios, asp.net-mvc, safari, single-page-application

On selecting the text in message and scrolling up or down the blue highlight comes over the textbox and navbar.
Note - this is not if we open the mobile site on computer this problem only turns up on mobile browser(safari on iOS).[image]

Comment: It can be issue with your mobile browser.

Comment: the problem is noticed on safari on ios and not tested for other brousers on mobile.
it doesnt matter issue is with browser or what but i need a fix.

Comment: So why are you posting here? Contact  Safari developing team or apple.

Comment: @SeM i need a code fix for this in my app if you try selecting something in whatsapp or any other website this doesn't happen right! so it shouldn't happen in my site too.

Comment: I tried increasing to z-index of header and footer didn't help.